# Can't get psfrag to replace text in pdf

Tags: pdf, psfrag

I have a PDF file converted to EPS using Acrobat 11. While I've successfully used psfrag in the same LaTeX document to replace text (replace font, basically) in EPS files generated by Matlab R2013a, I can't get the same done in the EPS generated by Acrobat. What could be the reason? The text that I'm trying to replace is single word, and I can see it in the EPS file when opened in Notepad. Any hints and suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is the word as a single string in the EPS surrendered by brackets as `(hello)` the usual reason fro psfrag failing is that the word has been typeset using ligatures or kerns so the full word does not appear as plain text in the internal EPS source.

Comment: @David: Yes exactly. So what's the workaround?

Comment: @MohammadImran There is no workaround. As long as the EPS file does not contain the string literally, there is _nothing_ that can be done. My general recommendation is not to rely on psfrag and generate all figures using LaTeX itself, so that you have a full control on the result.

Comment: @Yo: You mean the literal string that I see in the EPS is not really there? I see these two lines in the EPS when opened in Notepad:(Classifiers)
[9.36057 3.95929 6.24078 5.51782 5.51782 3.95929 4.68082 3.95929 6.12003 4.68085 0 ]xsh

Comment: If the literal string is in the EPS file, then `psfrag` should work of course. I don't know why it does not.

Comment: @yo I appreciate your suggestion for using LaTeX for graphics drawing but the tools that I saw on the Web require too steep a learning curve and the general consensus is that it is not worthwhile in case only a single publication is required to be typeset in LaTeX.

Comment: @David Carlisle: It felt wonderful to have been answered by two greats of the typesetting world - just viewed your profiles.

Comment: it's hard to say why it isn't working without the files but if that `(Classifiers)` is the string that you want to change, it probably works to change it to `()` so it is an empty string then instead of psfrag just use picture environment to position new text over our image.

Comment: @David Carlisle: I opened the file in Notepad and removed the string but now the PDF is generated only up to the point where I am inserting the EPS; the page containing the EPS and the ones after that are just not there. I guess I messed up the EPS somewhere. Anyway, many thanks for your time and suggestions.

Comment: oh xsh will be short for xshow which means that list of numbers are the character offsets so the string needs to be that long, don't use `()` use a string of length 11 but all spaces. that would also explain why psfrag doesn't work, as I recall it only works with show not xshow.

Comment: so if you are lucky you could replace `(Classifiers) [9.36057 3.95929 6.24078 5.51782 5.51782 3.95929 4.68082 3.95929 6.12003 4.68085 0 ]xsh` by `(Classifiers) show` and then use psfrag. perhaps:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In comments you added the relevant PostScript code:

```
(Classifiers)
[9.36057 3.95929 6.24078 5.51782 5.51782 3.95929 4.68082 3.95929 6.12003 4.68085 0 ]
xsh
```

`xsh` will be a defined alias in the file header for `xshow` the postscript command for letterspaced text, with the spacing being given by the numbers in the square brackets. `xshow` isn't supported by `psfrag` (I can't see why not, I think we just missed it at the time).

So you should be able to edit that command just to say

```
(Classifiers) 
show
```

and then `psfrag` will see it.

The following example includes an EPS file using each of these forms, and then includes it again after specifying a replacement for `Classifiers` note how just the non-letter spaced version is replaced.

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.eps}
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 5 295 85 365

/Times-Roman findfont 10 scalefont setfont


10 350 moveto
(Classifiers) [9.36057 3.95929 6.24078 5.51782 5.51782 3.95929 4.68082 3.95929 6.12003 4.68085 0 ] xshow

10 300 moveto
(Classifiers) show

showpage
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{psfrag}

\begin{document}


1: \fbox{\includegraphics{\jobname.eps}}

\psfrag{Classifiers}{\rotatebox{5}{\textbf{C}\textit{lass}\textsf{ifiers}}}%
2: \fbox{\includegraphics{\jobname.eps}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but somehow I'm not able to use the edited EPS files in my document. I am in Windows environment and I edit the EPS in Notepad. The generated PDF document just stops short of the page where I am inserting the edited FPS. Could it have something to do with mismatched line endings resulting from use of Notepad?

Comment: @MohammadImran line endings should  should not make a difference, postscript considers all any combination of \r and \n as a line end. Note of it doesn't work for you you do not have to accept the answer! (leaving it not accepted makes it more likely that some provides a different answer). You could also email me the EPS file if you wish (if you google my name you'll see my email address)

Comment: Thumbs up @David! Got it finally working using your suggested solution. And yes, it was the line ending issue, I got a confirmation from (https://forums.adobe.com/thread/674536?start=0&tstart=0). I edited the file in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 editor (yes!) and it apparently didn't mess up the line endings. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @MohammadImran that's odd, but glad you got it working:-)

Comment: I've created a simple [script](https://gist.github.com/ondrejtichacek/068024b000ae5e0b27f6403ddbdfaea3) for replacing the `xsh` tag in eps files. This solution works for me well enough.

Comment: @Ondrian if it's going to be useful I suppose we should update psfrag to support xshow, as I said originally it can't be hard (or at least it wouldn't have been hard 20 years ago when i could remember what it was doing:-)